# How can I post code coverage from a combined C++/Javascript Node.js addon to Coveralls.io?

Tags: node.js, lcov, coveralls

I have a [Node.js module](https://github.com/geo-data/node-mapserv) composed of both a C++ addon and Javascript library code.  It includes command line generated code coverage analysis using `lcov` for the C++ and [`istanbul`](https://npmjs.org/package/istanbul) for the Javascript. The output from both is in lcov format which can be nicely combined in the completed coverage report.  See `make cover` in the [`Makefile`](https://github.com/geo-data/node-mapserv/blob/master/Makefile) for details.

My question is how do I post the output of this combined code coverage for display in [Coveralls](https://coveralls.io/)?  [I have tried](https://github.com/geo-data/node-mapserv/commit/46392f288943cd348d9ba7cc55be13437c295358) using [node-coveralls](https://github.com/cainus/node-coveralls) but this only handles the javascript in the module and as far as I can see [cpp-coveralls](https://github.com/eddyxu/cpp-coveralls) only handles the C++.  Is there perhaps a way to combine the output of the two and post the result to Coveralls?

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 1):

I would try running both [node-coveralls](https://github.com/cainus/node-coveralls) and [cpp-coveralls](https://github.com/eddyxu/cpp-coveralls) and dumping their payload instead of sending it directly to [coveralls.io](https://coveralls.io/). I would then combine the two json file into one and post it to [coveralls.io](https://coveralls.io/).

Comment: Thanks for the response but although cpp-coveralls supports the `--dump` option to output to JSON, there is no such support that I could find in node-coveralls; it posts the JSON straight off to coveralls.io.

Comment: The beauty of open source and github lets you either send them a patch to enable that option, or simply requesting it from the devs: https://github.com/cainus/node-coveralls

Comment: @HommeZwaagstra if you like opensource project, let's give them some help or some money: this will make the developers happy to help you :-)